# Material Design UI (advanced animation) in Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, user-interface, animation, material-design

What is the best way to go about implementing something this [heavy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8TXgCzxEnw) on animation for android? (drop shadows, ease, etc)

I found one easy way to get this effect; by animating my UI using tweens in the timeline of an 'AppContainer' class and just setting up my document class as follows:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

    public class Groot extends MovieClip {

        public var appContainer = new AppContainer;


    public function Groot() {

            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;          
            appContainer.width = stage.stageWidth;
            appContainer.height = stage.stageHeight;
            addChild(appContainer);         
        }

}
}
```

From there its just an issue of event lesteners and gotoAndPlay/Stop(); commands. However if I don't want borders on the 'wrong' aspect ratio, I'll have to use:

```
StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT
```

as well as relative object positioning. (This wouldn't be a huge problem in itself, save for all the complex animation required). This kind of rules out working with any timelines, and that's where I'm left clueless.

Now, I *am* able to set up a class to handle relative positioning rather easily with a method like this:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

    public class Groot extends MovieClip {

        var pos = new PositionHandler();
        var appContainer = new AppContainer;

    public function Groot() {

            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;          
            pos.startPos(appContainer)
            addChild(appContainer);         
        }

}
}
```

with a class to handle the various relative position functions:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;

    public class PositionHandler {

        public function PositionHandler() {
            // constructor code
        }
        public function startPos(obj:MovieClip):void {
            obj.width = stage.stageWidth;
            obj.height = stage.stageHeight;
        }

    }

}
```

This is all well and good if I want to position UI components statically, but to animate them dynamically, moving from one relative position to another? From a custom class no less? I have no idea... (Let alone animating the drop shadows / potential shape changes / color wipes etc) any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: 1st) The video was created in a professional video editing tool. It's not in anyway a screen cast. 2nd) in Actionscript running on Android, I don't think you'll ever get that level of smoothness. 3rd) If you want to use the android framework: 5.0 draw the shadows automatically for you and use the `.animate()` method on views and the `ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal` for the circular animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash doesn't really support 'relative' sizing and positioning out of the box. But there's no reason you can't extend it to give you this sort of behavior.

It's a bit of an undertaking though, as it basically boils down to writing a layout framework. But you can do something a bit dirtier.

A starting point could be to extend Sprite, then override it's width/height getters/setters. Instead of letting flash scale the Sprite for you, you can define your own logic to respond to what you think 'width' and 'height' mean.

Then you could provide 'proportionalWidth' and 'proportionalHeight' getters/setters.

```
functionCalledFrameAfterAnyLayoutValuesChanged()
{
    if ( proportionalWidth is defined )
        widthToLayoutTo = proportionalWidth  * parent.width;
    else
        widthToLayoutTo = width;

    if ( proportionalHeight is defined )
        heightToLayoutTo = proportionalHeight * parent.height;
    else
        heightToLayoutTo = height;

    // Perform whatever logic you need to make your Sprite scaled to widthToLayoutTo / heightToLayoutTo 
    ...
}
```

Something similar could be done with 'proportionalX' and 'proportionalY' to get relative positioning.

You could build a bag of components that extend this class, overriding the bespoke stuff for each.

You're then free to tween these 'relative' properties any way you like. I suggest using a library like GTween.
http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/

Comment: This helped alot, thank you! I've also found some good tools to start with [here](http://greensock.com/).